# Approximation of the Lerch zeta function

Tags: integration, summation, asymptotics, special-functions, analytic-number-theory

I come across the statement in [this paper](https://smallpdf.com/result#r=586ab4c2e504e839ff30f7f10ed907d8&t=share-document), title "Garunkstis, R. and Laurincikas, A. (1996). On the Lerch zeta-function", pp. 342. It states that
\begin{align*} \sum_{y<n\leq N} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^s} &= \frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\color{red}{\sum_{y<n\leq N}} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}} - \int_y^N \color{red}{\sum_{y<n\leq x}} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}}\,d\frac{1}{(x+u)^{\sigma}}\\ &= \int_y^N \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda v}}{(v+u)^s}\,dv+\frac{B_\lambda}{N^{\sigma}}+\color{blue}{\frac{B_{\lambda}}{\sigma}\frac{1}{y^{\sigma}}} \end{align*}
using partial summation. However when I apply Abel's summation formula, I find that
\begin{align*} \sum_{y<n\leq N} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^s} 
&= \sum_{y<n\leq N} \overbrace{\frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}}}^{a_n} \overbrace{\frac{1}{(n+u)^{\sigma}}}^{\phi(n)}\\ 
&= \frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\color{red}{\sum_{0\leq n\leq N}} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}}-\frac{1}{(y+u)^{\sigma}}\color{red}{\sum_{0\leq n\leq y}} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}} - \int_y^N \color{red}{\sum_{0\leq n\leq x}} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}}\frac{-\sigma}{(x+u)^{\sigma+1}}\,dx\\ 
&=?\\
&= \frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\color{red}{\sum_{y<n\leq N}} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}} + \int_y^N \color{red}{\sum_{y<n\leq x}} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}}\frac{\sigma}{(x+u)^{\sigma+1}}\,dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\bigg(\int_y^N  \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda x}}{(x+u)^{it}}\,dx+B_{\lambda}\bigg)+\int_y^N \bigg(\int_y^x \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda v}}{(v+u)^{it}}\,dv+B_{\lambda}\bigg)\frac{\sigma}{(x+u)^{\sigma+1}}\,dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\int_y^N \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda x}}{(x+u)^{it}}\,dx+\frac{B_{\lambda}}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\\ 
&\quad+ \int_{y}^N \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda v}}{(v+u)^{it}} \int_v^N \frac{\sigma}{(x+u)^{\sigma+1}}\,dx\,dv+B_{\lambda}\int_y^N \frac{\sigma}{(x+u)^{\sigma+1}}\,dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\int_y^N \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda x}}{(x+u)^{it}}\,dx+\frac{B_{\lambda}}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}\\ 
&\quad+ \int_{y}^N \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda v}}{(v+u)^{it}} \bigg(-\frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}+\frac{1}{(v+u)^{\sigma}}\bigg)\,dv+B_{\lambda}\bigg(-\frac{1}{(N+u)^{\sigma}}+\frac{1}{(y+u)^{\sigma}}\bigg)\\ 
&= \int_y^N \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda v}}{(v+u)^s}\,dv+\frac{B_\lambda}{N^{\sigma}}+\color{blue}{\frac{B_{\lambda}}{y^{\sigma}}} \end{align*}
here we have used the property in the paper, namely
\begin{align*} \sum_{y<n\leq N} \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda n}}{(n+u)^{it}}= \int_y^N  \frac{e^{2\pi i\lambda x}}{(x+u)^{it}}\,dx+B_{\lambda} \end{align*}
The question mark is on why the sum starts from $y+1$ instead of $0$? The second is on why the blue color part is different from the statement they give? A side note: The constant $B_{\lambda}$ is like a bound and could be written as $B_{\lambda}/(N+u)^{\sigma}=O(N^{-\sigma})$, hence I could absorb the negative sign previously, and $x$ and $v$ are just dummy variables. In that sense $\frac{B_{\lambda}}{\sigma}\frac{1}{y^{\sigma}}=O(y^{-\sigma})$ and will be the same as what I have. I would be appreciated if someone could help me with the missing $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ part and the missing $\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sigma}}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you define $a_n=0$ for $n\leq y$ when using the Abel summation formula? In that way, your red sums will start at $y+1$.

Comment: also the missing $\sigma $: you've written $1/\sigma =\mathcal O(1)$ in your third from last sentence, but you can't do this since $\sigma $ is potentially close to 0

Comment: @Gary Why can we define in such way?

Comment: @求石莫得 Why not?$\,$

Comment: @tomos In the paper they have stated that $0<\sigma\leq1$, so I think it will not be a problem.

Comment: @求石莫得 Why would that condition guarantee that $\sigma$ is not close to zero? If $\sigma =10^{-1000}$ then it still holds that $0<\sigma \leq 1$.

Comment: @Gary You are right, $\sigma$ may still be close to zero. Do you know how to get the missing $\frac{1}{\sigma}$, or my method above has some error?